# bquote, parsing, expression to get multiple lines labels in ggplot with greek letters and variables as subscripts

Tags: r, parsing, ggplot2, expression, plotmath

Let's say I have

```
paste0("Year = ",index,"\nN = ",length((dfGBD %>% filter(year==index))[[vbl]]),
                                  " Bandwidth = ",round(stats::bw.nrd(log((dfGBD %>% filter(year == index))[[vbl]])),2),
                                  "\nSkewness:", round(e1071::skewness(log((dfGBD %>% filter(year==index))[[vbl]])), 2),
                                  " Kurtosis:",round(e1071::kurtosis(log((dfGBD %>% filter(year==index))[[vbl]])),2),
                                  "\nmu[",vbl,"] = ", round(mean((dfGBD %>% filter(year==index))[[vbl]]),2),
                                  " sigma[",vbl,"] = ",round(sd((dfGBD %>% filter(year==index))[[vbl]]),2)
                                  )
```

inside a `sapply` through `index` years. Further, `vbl` is a string with the name of a variable. The `sapply` produces a vector of `labels` for a `factor` variable.
Applying `ggplot` I obtain labels similar to the next:

```
Year = 2000
N = 195 Bandwidth = 0.09
Skewness: 0 Kurtosis: -0.56
mu[Mortality] = 7750.85 sigma[Mortality] = 1803.28
```

Till here, all ok. I have already written `mu[vbl]`, `sigma[vbl]` thinking in parsing and subscript notation to get the greek letters with the name of the variable saved in `vbl` as subscript.

First I tried `facet_wrap` with option `labeller = "label_parsed"`. I obtained an error which I only solved writting the string between backticks ``` `` ```, but then `\n` has no effect. I tried many options using `bquote` and/or `parse` and/or `expression` and/or `atop` etc. in order to get this multiple lines result with the desired output I described above. But only get or one line or very ugly outputs or, mostly, errors, and I couldn't see yet the greek letters.

So what/how should I do?

PS: as answered in other `stackoverflow`'s, `\n` does not work in this context, so a list with `bquote`'s for each line is suggested. I tried it, but then I got an error that I think is due to incompatibility of number of elements of all the lists and number of labels of a factor (a `label` may not be a `list`?).

Thank you!